# date is not presented correctly

Tags: php, mysql, date

I insert my date with the Now() mysql function, and when I select the date I use this:

```
DATE_FORMAT(com.date,'%h:%i  %d/%m/%Y ')
```

Basically, the output that I get is the same, no matter what time I enter the input (The date is correct, but the time is incorrect):

12:00 20/11/2011

How can I correct this?!?

Comment: What is the type of `com.date`? (And what do you mean by "The date is correct, but the date is incorrect"?)

Comment: "The date is correct, but the date is incorrect" - You might want to elaborate a bit with your question to get any help. I imagine it may be something to do with the data type of the field definition but given the vague question, who knows!

Comment: it is date...sorry date is correct but time is incorrect.. may it be that the time on my machine is incorrect..By what I can see I do have the correct time on my machine..  I store the Now() as Date in my database

Comment: So `com.date` is a column of type `DATE`? I.e., a type that does not store a time value?

Comment: should I store it as varchar(20) instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysql set current timestamp when you use now() function. So it should be correct output when you query by
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(com.date,'%h:%i  %d/%m/%Y ')

I assume your com.date column is a timestamp, not a date.